# How to prevent UIScrollView from getting pushed down, when the scene is embedded in a NavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a rather complex setup of custom views. A StackView inside a ScrollView etc.

Everything works fine until I embed my ViewController inside a NavigationController. (took me way too long to figure that out.. *grinch*)

> How it should look like:
>   [image: Wanted result (without NavigationController)]
>
> How it looks like with NavigationController
>   [image]

I think that this has something to do with the NavigationBar. However as I am fairly new to iOS developing I can not figure out what to change.

If you want to take a look, I have created a GitHub repo under:

https://github.com/Shanakor/ScrollViewIssue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in your ViewController. That fixes your problem.

[image: Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets]

---

**Explanation:**

Since iOS 7, Apple has change how ViewControllers with UIScrollViews are displayed.

When the first subview of a ViewController is a `UIScrollView`, the UIScrollView it will be rendered beginning from the top of the ViewController - even if a `UINavigationBar` is on top -- unless you uncheck that button or set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` programmatically.

Comment: Would you care to explain, why this fixes my issue? What is this option for and what does the system do or try to do?

Comment: Ohh. Ok that makes sense. Thank you so much. I guess this is to provide a better look and feel in iOS apps as the content is scrolled until under the navigation bar.

Comment: Exactly, that's the reason :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`  in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

For more Information, check [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin).

Hope this helped.